# Does ruby gem caracal have an option for subscript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caracal

I was going through the documentation for caracal gem in ruby, i noticed that it had the option for superscript tags, but could not find one for subscript, any ideas?

Comment: seems you can use `vertical_align :subscript` just like you can use `vertical_align :superscript` [Spec](https://github.com/urvin-compliance/caracal/blob/562bdc4ceff095d467deca74acdfda5b45c20929/spec/lib/caracal/core/models/text_model_spec.rb)